# Object Destructure in TS with and without explicit variable

Tags: typescript

In TS, This code compiles successfully...

```
let amir = {email: 'amir@example.com', admin: true}

function sendEmail({email}: {email: string}): string {
  return `Emailing ${email}`
}

sendEmail(amir)
```

However, this code,

```
function extractEmail({email}: {email: string}): string {
  return `Emailing ${email}`
}

extractEmail({email: 'amir@example.com', user: 'admin'})
```

throws error:

```
Argument of type '{ email: string; user: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ email: string; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'user' does not exist in type '{ email: string; }'.(2345)
```

How does explicity declaring the object in a let makes the code different?

Comment: Object literals just get special treatment, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks, it's an unusual inconsistency but the notion is that it will help detect typos etc, why would you provide a literal with properties other than those required, is the idea.

Comment: What about if you make it a const?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Countingstuff, the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) explains the reasoning, but it fails to mention a key point: *if you pass a literal object with excess properties to a function, there is no way to access those properties anywhere*, so it makes sense to flag them as errors. If the code below would be valid, the `x` property would always be pointless:

```
f({a: 1, x: true})
function f(a: {a: number}) {
  console.log(a.x) // cannot access `x` here
}
// cannot access `x` here either
```

The same thing happens when assigning a literal object to a variable or a constant with a narrower type:

```
const a: {a: number} = {a: 1, x: true}
console.log(a.x) // cannot access `x`
```

However, if you first assign the literal to a variable or constant, it is no longer necessarily an error:

```
const o = {a: 1, x: true}
function f(a: {a: number}) {
  console.log(a.x) // still cannot access `x` here
}
console.log(o.x) // but here we can
```

And similarly for an assignment to a narrower type:

```
const o = {a: 1, x: true}
const a: {a: number} = o
console.log(o.x)
```